# Real-time updates ASP.NET using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, signalr, azure-sql-database, sqldependency

I am trying to make a proof of concept where a simple ASP.NET web application that is using Entity framework updates automatically when a record is added to my Azure SQL Database. I did some research and stumbled across SignalR and SqlDependency. At first sight this seems exactly what I want but according to this:

[Creating a Query for Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181122.aspx)

There are a lot of restrictions if I want to use SqlDependency. Like I can't do something like this:

```
context.table.Take(100).Skip(50).ToList();
```

Because this would result in a `SELECT TOP` and that is not permitted according to the previous link. I also don't want to get the whole table because that would be over 100 000 records and that would cause performance issues.

Is there a way to have real time data (only like the last 20 inserted records) from my azure SQL database shown on my ASP.NET web application? Preferably not with a periodic refresh but only if a record is inserted.

Comment: Instead of trying to signal in response to a database event, have the code that inserts tha data also raise the signal. It's much simpler and faster this way

Comment: I don't have control over the code that inserts the records into the table. This is done by an added package. I also don't want to change any code in this package.

Comment: Unfortunately [Azure SQL databases don't support Service Broker](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-transact-sql-information/), which is required to use SqlDependency..

Comment: Oh, guess I have to go with a whole new plan. Are there any other technologies available that somehow broadcast database changes to applications?